# why to register struct cdev in driver code

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

This may be a novice question, but please help me to understand it.

Why exactly do we need to register the struct cdev in our character driver?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, you seem to be asking about the significance of `struct cdev`. `struct cdev` is one of the elements of the `inode` structure. As you probably may know already, an `inode` structure is used by the kernel internally to represent files. The `struct cdev` is the kernel's internal structure that represents char devices. So `cdev* i_cdev` field of `struct inode` is a pointer to cdev structure while the `inode` refers to the char device file. Therefore if the kernel has to invoke the character device, it has to register a structure of `cdev` type.

Answer (score 24):

`struct cdev` represent a character device within the kernel.

All streaming devices(*ex: uart, keyboard*) falls under the character device category and is available in user-space as a **device node file** (*ex: /dev/ttyS0*). User applications accesses the device by using the standard File I/O operations.

[image]

Inside kernel, character driver comes in between the device file and the streaming device, and this driver layer takes care of translating the File I/O operation to Device operations and vice-versa.

In character device driver development `struct file_operations` is the most important data structure used. This structure is used to implement the basic file i/o - *open(), read(), write(), close(), ioctl(), etc...* functionality for the the device.

`struct cdev` structure encapsulates the `file_operations` structure and some other important driver information(major/minor no). It is the new way of registering character driver with kernel.

The cdev structure is accessed by the kernel through the following API's:

```
cdev_init() - used to initialize struct cdev with the defined file_operations
cdev_add()  - used to add a character device to the system. 
cdev_del()  - used to remove a character device from the system
```

After a call to `cdev_add()`, your device is immediately alive. All functions you defined (through the file_operations structure) can be called.

Comment: The question was relevant, and I am not sure I really got the full picture:
In http://free-electrons.com/doc/books/ldd3.pdf, the scull.c driver defines a cdev and  passes a fops struct to it as well as to the file descriptor (struct file also have a member fops). 
I understand the need to pass a struct fops to the file descriptor (so your methods get called when the user read/write the file), but why would we need a cdev strcuture with the same fops info?